# How to have app create spreadsheet on user's account but use resources from mine

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

From the [next last version of my app](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxXiX0dW5Yn554gfPIa60uFK21E20HaADp4KqJ2IDIqFb0A3NMP/exec), I ran into the problem of the user having to send access request because the spreadsheet the app is supposed to create created the spreadsheet on my account. So, yesterday, I thought I would fix that by having it use the user's account instead. I got the [app update](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxXiX0dW5Yn554gfPIa60uFK21E20HaADp4KqJ2IDIqFb0A3NMP/exec) up today. It does use the user's account, but for all resources requested.

The app requires both an image and a base Google spreadsheet on my account, but because it's using the user's account for everything, it seems to have access to neither. Namely, my spreadsheet-access code is like:

```
var baseSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MvzDMc_f6CYkCt3EQBl-CmgcQ_FNMoIGgTYLilCCgh8/edit#gid=0');
var newSpreadsheet = baseSheet.copy(nameOfSpreadsheet);
```

and the image code is this HTML element:

```
 <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0By8fFJhNOgyCOTlPWF9yYWk0bkk" class="hidden pageCenter">
```

How do I make the content at those URLs accessible for everyone, while, at the same time, making sure that the output Sheet is created on user's account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the permissions are set to "view by anyone" on both the base sheet and the image.

Comment: I was able to that thus: 

- in Google Sheets, I simply got a URL for the base spreadsheet at which any user can view
- in Google Drive, I also got sharable link. Luckily, for me, this one I didn't have to update in my code base.

Comment: Great news @MikeWarren. I find permissions problems the most frustrating with apps scripting, however, it is necessary for keeping everything secure. One of those frustrations you just have to get used to.